# OneDrive file only uploads when app is terminated

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, onedrive

I'm having a problem uploading a file to OneDrive from a universal app that I can't understand or figure out how to debug. I used [this guide](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/708863/Developer-Guide-to-Write-Windows-Store-App-usi) to go through the process of getting file IDs and such and it worked great until a few hours ago.

Now I can get folder and file ids, so I assume that I am still successfully connecting to OneDrive and my internet connection is still working. But when I step into the BackgroundUploadAsync the thread or whatever that was was executing before never returns. In the code below, the message "Uploading new file to OneDrive..." never disappears.

Strangely, while it is uploading I can refresh my OneDrive folder on ie and I'll never see what I'm trying to upload. But once I stop the debugger, or terminate the app on the phone, I can instantly refresh and the file will be there.

Here is the method for uploading:

```
public async Task UploadToOneDrive(string folderID, string localFileName)
    {
        try
        {
            StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(localFileName);
            string fileName = "backup-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM") + ".db";
            await file.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder, fileName, NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(fileName);

            await connectClient.BackgroundUploadAsync(folderID,
                fileName, file, OverwriteOption.Overwrite);
        }
        catch (LiveConnectException)
        {
            MessageDialog m = new MessageDialog("Could not connect to to OneDrive. Cloud sync will be stopped.");
            m.ShowAsync();
        }
        catch (LiveAuthException)
        {
            MessageDialog m = new MessageDialog("Error authenticating OneDrive service. Please try cloud sync again later.");
            m.ShowAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageDialog m = new MessageDialog("Unknown exception occurred.\n\nError:{0}", ex.Message);
            m.ShowAsync();
        }
    }
```

And here is the sync process

```
public async Task sync()
    {
        var sb = StatusBar.GetForCurrentView();
        sb.ProgressIndicator.Text = "Syncing with OneDrive...";
        await sb.ProgressIndicator.ShowAsync();

        string cloudFolderID = await syncManager.CreateOrGetOneDriveFolderID("GlucoseCalculator", "Documents/");
        string cloudFileID = await syncManager.GetFileID(DataManager.sqlFileName, "Documents/GlucoseCalculator/");

        try
        {

            if (cloudFileID != null)
            {
                if (!(await dbManager.DoesFileExist(DataManager.sqlFileName)))
                {
                    sb.ProgressIndicator.Text = "Downloading file from OneDrive...";
                    await syncManager.DownloadFromOneDrive(cloudFileID, DataManager.sqlFileName);
                    goto BREAK;
                }

                DateTime cloudLastEditDateTime = DateTime.Parse(await syncManager.GetFileProperty(cloudFileID, "updated_time"));
                DateTime localLastEditDateTime = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(DataManager.sqlFileName).GetResults().GetBasicPropertiesAsync().GetResults().DateModified.DateTime;

                if (cloudLastEditDateTime > localLastEditDateTime)
                {
                    sb.ProgressIndicator.Text = "Downloading file from OneDrive...";
                    await syncManager.DownloadFromOneDrive(cloudFileID, DataManager.sqlFileName);
                }

                else if (cloudLastEditDateTime < localLastEditDateTime)
                {
                    sb.ProgressIndicator.Text = "Uploading file to OneDrive...";
                    await syncManager.UploadToOneDrive(cloudFolderID, DataManager.sqlFileName);
                }

            }
            else if (cloudFileID == null)
            {
                sb.ProgressIndicator.Text = "Uploading new file to OneDrive...";                                
                await syncManager.UploadToOneDrive(cloudFolderID, DataManager.sqlFileName);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            sb.ProgressIndicator.Text = "Cloud synchronization failed.";
            sb.ProgressIndicator.HideAsync();
            return;
        }

        sb.ProgressIndicator.Text = "Synchronization complete!";
        BREAK:;
        await sb.ProgressIndicator.HideAsync();
    }
```

Comment: After combing through a ton of Microsoft account settings and stuff I finally found out how to revoke app permissions. I did that for my app, uninstalled it, restarted my computer and it seems to be working now. Still no idea what caused the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you are creating some object that implements `IDisposible`, but it is not in a `using` block. Maybe the `StorageFile`.

Comment: I tried going through all of my code from the moment the sync button is clicked to the upload point, but nothing seems to implement IDisposable. I'm new to programming, so I did that by assuming that the object has to have the Dispose() method. But I also tried to be safe and put the storage file in a using, and it gave an error saying that it must be implicitly convertible to IDisposable.